# How do I convert this IIS URL Rewrite Rule for .htaccess Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

How do I convert this IIS URL Rewrite Rule for .htaccess Apache?

```
<rule name="View Trades/Wants">
                    <match url="^([^]+)/PD([^]+)/" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="trade.php?type={R:1}&amp;id={R:2}" />
                </rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^]+)/PD([^]+)/ /trade.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Make sure you turn the rewrite engine on if you haven't already:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the [L] mean?

Comment: @EthanAllen It means stop rewriting for the current iteration: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l